# Oddo - Print selected records of tree view from wizard to pdf

Tags: drop-down-menu, server, treeview, odoo-10, wizard

I have to print list of selected record of treeview  into pdf report from wizard , i am add new menu item into print dropdwon menu as in following figure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBeZp.png)

i neeed help

Answer (score 0):

I created wizard it will search record with from date and to date, you need it for pdf you can write template as pdf, i think it may help you

```
class WizardContract(models.TransientModel):
_name = 'order.wizard'
customer_ids=fields.Many2one('res.partner',string='Customer Name' )
datefrom = fields.Date(string="Date From")
dateto = fields.Date(string="Date To")
current_date= fields.datetime.now()     

@api.depends('customer_ids','datefrom','dateto')
def print_report(self):

    search_id = self.env['sale.order'].search([('partner_id','=', self.customer_ids.id),('date_order', '>=', self.datefrom), ('date_order', '<=', self.dateto)])
    lst = []
    for loop in search_id:
        lst.append(str(loop.partner_id.name))
        lst.append(str(self.datefrom))
        lst.append(str(self.current_date))
    lines=[]
    if self.current_date:
        current_date= str(self.current_date)
        total=0     
        lines=[]
        rec_sale_line = self.env['sale.order.line'].search([('order_id','=', loop.id),('order_partner_id','=', self.customer_ids.id)])
        for line in rec_sale_line:
            dict_lines = {'product_id':line.product_id.id,
                          'product_uom_qty':line.product_uom_qty,
                          'price_unit':line.price_unit,
                          'sub_total':line.price_subtotal
                }
            lines.append(dict_lines)
    partner_id=lst[0] 
    data = {
                'partner_id': partner_id,
                'confirmation_date': fields.Datetime.now(),
                'lst':lst,
                'lines':lines,
                }
    print line.product_id.name
    print line
    print type(lst)

    return self.env['report'].get_action([],'order_log.report_template_demo',data=data)
```